# save a column in a cell

Tags: r

I want to supplement the email addresses from the column df$email with text and save everything in one cell.

For example:

```
before_Email1@mail.com_after
before_Email2@mail.com_after
before_Email3@mail.com_after
```

"before_" and "_after" are the text  I want to add

this is my code:

```
colText = paste0("before_",df$email,"_after")

for (i in 1:nrow(colText)) {
  colText = paste0(colText,"before_",df$email[i],"_after")

}
```

Comment: `paste` is vectorised. You don't need a loop. `paste0('before_', df$email, '_after')` should work fine. Also make sure your column is character (not factor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `df` is your data frame which you are working on. If you are using `paste0` in your code it already reads a vector so the loop is unnecessary, simply using `paste0` will do the trick:

```
df$email<- as.character(df$email) # converting to character before concat

paste0('before_', df$email, '_after')
```

The above should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is worthy to have a try with `gsub("(.*)","before_\\1_after",df$email)`